# jQuery plugin function call to its own method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code below and essentially it takes an element as input (i.e.):

```
$(#someDiv).Calculator();
```

but the problem is that I want to call this plugin's function within itself, but I don't know how to get an object/handle to itself to call the function.  caching off "this" does not have the proper reference.

```
(function ($) {
    jQuery.fn.Calculator = function () {

        var selectedObjects = this;
        var control = $(selectedObjects[0])[0];

    $("#btnCalculate").click(function(){
        // this is where calculate needs to be called
        someObject.calculate(...);
    });

        return {
            calculate: function (value) {

                // do some code    
                return selectedObjects;
            }
        };
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Any ideas/direction would be of great help!  Thank you all!

Comment: How about storing the object in a variable called `someObject` before you return it?

Comment: Also, you may want to take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
(function ($) {
    jQuery.fn.Calculator = function () {

        var selectedObjects = this;
        var control = $(selectedObjects[0])[0];

        $("#btnCalculate").click(function(){
            // this is where calculate needs to be called
            calculator.calculate(...);
        });

        var calculator = {
            calculate: function (value) {

                // do some code    
                return selectedObjects;
            }
        };

        return calculator;
    }
})(jQuery);
```